# Raw_input to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Is there a way to take a raw_input, record it to memory, then call it in a subprocess?

```
x = raw_input("what is your fav. Color??")
Subprocess.Popen("C://Windows/system32/cmd.exe")
os.system('echo your favorite color is "x"')
```

My main need for this is so that I can take a user's raw_input and incorporate that into a command line program my friend made.

Comment: Can you pass it as a command-line parameter to your friend's program?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, you get your input using `raw_input`

```
x = raw_input('Input:')
```

And then send it to subprocess command which is invoking your friend's binary like this

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['yourfriendsbinary'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

out,err = p.communicate(input=x)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass it as a command-line parameter like Space_COwbOy has mentioned, or you could open a pipe, and if that sub-process listens on std-input, setup the std-input of the subprocess so that it's redirected to the output pipe of the parent process.  Then when you feed the data through the pipe from the parent, the subprocess will pick up the output from the parent as if it was reading from standard-input.